# MVC html.DropdownFor: binding the list and the selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, modelstate

I'm using a model state check. So when there is an error I want to return the user the same model that was filled out. My form however has `html.DropDownListFor`.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.SelectedId, Model.ItemList)
```

The drop down list will error saying that my select list (`Model.ItemList`) is null. This is because the `dropDownListFor` bound the selected value correctly but now the list is null on my post action. Is there a default way to solve this. With the list itself getting bound and the selected value.

I know I could do a `html.HiddenFor` and bind the whole list with like something like:

```
<input name="name[0].Id" type="text" />
<input name="name[1].Id" type="text" />
<input name="name[2].Id" type="text" />
```

Or I could even write my own extension to do this for me.

Right now on the post action I am just repopulating the select list, but I was curious is there was another way as my searches did not come up with anything.

Comment: No. That is the correct way. You need to repopulate the list because http is stateless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there isn't any built in functionality that would help with model state and select list.

As this link refers to that as much as well.
http://benfoster.io/blog/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc